# adb shell am get-standby-bucket returns always 5

Tags: android, adb

When forcing the app standby-bucket

`adb shell am set-standby-bucket <package> rare`

and then getting the stand by mode using

`adb shell am get-standby-bucket <package>`

adb returns always `5` regardless of the set mode.

What does 5 mean and how to get this work as it should be? 5 is none of specified modes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#getAppStandbyBucket()

Sometimes this works as it should be for a very short period of time after removing and reinstalling the app but then stops working for unknown reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information is not depicted as clearly as it probably could be, but in the link you provided, under STANDBY_BUCKET_ACTIVE, it says:

> Standby bucket values that are ≤ STANDBY_BUCKET_ACTIVE will not be throttled by the system while they are in this bucket. Buckets > STANDBY_BUCKET_ACTIVE will most likely be restricted in some way. For instance, jobs and alarms may be deferred.

That is, 5 means no throttling.